# get id of street names and regions with php regex

Tags: php, regex

i need get id, i have name of some street or road or square and name of some region or place... so i need get id from string where i have word1 and word2.

i'm trying this:

```
<?php
$pattern = '~^(?<id>\\S)\\t+[name1qaz]+[\\w\'-]+[\\w\'-]+[name2asd]+[\\w\'-]~mi';
$subject = '1 name1qaz avenue (name2qwe region) 
2 name1wsx road (name2asd region) 
3 name1edc street (name2zxc region) 
4 name1qaz square name2asd place 
5 name1wsx avenue (name2qwe region) 
7 name1edc street (name2zxc place) 
8 name1qaz road name2zxc region 
9 name1wsx square (name2asd region)';
$result = preg_match( $pattern, $subject , $matches );
echo $result;
print_r($matches);
?>
```

in result i receive empty array

Comment: your pattern is wrong. `<id>` does not exist in your text, so cannot match anything. Your `\\\` everywhere are actually escaping the backslashes, causing the engine to look for literal backslashes.

Comment: please help me with correct pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong. Use this:

```
$pattern = '~^(?<id>\d+)\s+name1qaz\s+(?=.*?name2asd\b)~mi';
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/g4qxDV

Comment: also place or region can be witout ()

Comment: @user2368299: See the demo. I am using first square brackets for capturing group #1 and 2nd square bracket for positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$pattern = '~([0-9]+)[ ]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[ ]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[ ]?\(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[ ]?([a-zA-Z]+)\)~';

preg_match_all($patterm, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

I got sort of lost reading your pattern, so I wrote what I would do to match the lines in your string.  I wasn't 100% about whether you wanted all of the information returned as individual values so I included all words/numbers between the spaces in the resulting array.

Comment: i need only id and place or region can be witout ()

Comment: If you only need the id from the beginning then '~^([0-9]{1,})~gm' I believe would do the trick.